Error [rospack] Error: package 'rosbag_storage' not found when using bag_reader.exe on Windows
I have compiled a bag_reader.exe program using VS2019 on a Windows environment to read ROS bag files. While the program works perfectly fine in the ROS environment, I encounter the following error when running it on Windows:
[rospack] Error: package 'rosbag_storage' not found

Here are my configurations and attempted solutions:
Environment Variables:
I have ensured that the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable is set correctly, pointing to the path containing the rosbag_storage package:
set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\share

ROS Installation:
I am using ROS on Windows and have followed the official installation guide to complete the setup.
Package Installation:
I have confirmed that the rosbag_storage package is installed. I tested it in a Linux environment, and it works fine there.
Dependencies:
I checked the dependencies of bag_reader.exe and ensured that all dependencies are installed and paths are correct.
Compilation Configuration:
While compiling bag_reader.exe, I have correctly added the libraries and include paths related to rosbag_storage in the CMakeLists.txt.
Despite these efforts, I still encounter the above error at runtime. I have also tried the following steps for further troubleshooting:
Manually checked if the rosbag_storage package exists in the path specified by ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.
Used the rospack find rosbag_storage command to confirm that the rosbag_storage package can be found.
My questions are:
Are there any other configurations or checks I need to perform?
Is there another way to resolve this package not found issue?
I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you very much!
